# pi 3 not booting to black screen after changing host name

Tags: boot-issues

It was working fine until I decided to change the hostname. Now the green light next to the red one doesn't turn on, no input is detected through HDMI, while VNC and PUTTY both time out.

I've tried unplugging everything and plugging it back in.

the weird thing is that I changed the hostname only a few minutes prior. Today is the first time using it in months and I didn't have an extra keyboard but I did have another mouse, Trying to connected to VNC wasn't working so I used the right-click cut command to change the hostname from raspberrypi to berrypi. The pi rebooted and everything worked, I was able to connect just fine.

Now that I could connect with VNC I changed the name again to blackpi, as the pi is in a black case, it asked me to reboot but I clicked no and altered the name to blackPi, that time I rebooted and that's how I ran into this situation.

Comment: can you read the sd card on your computer? if the green LED doesn't even flicker it's a sign that the pi can't see that there's an SD card in the slot

Comment: @JaromandaX after plugging it into my computer the computer said it needed to be repaired. after repairing the green light flashes, but everything else is the same.

Comment: does the contents look right?

Comment: @JaromandaX here is an image of the folder https://imgur.com/gallery/wzJ0rjo